# Обьекты и ссылки в Java

Tags: java, объекты, коллекции, linked-list

**Описание:**
При удалении из `cacheMatrix`, объекты удаляются отовсюду(из matrix).

**Вопрос:**
 Не могу понять как это работает, и как предотвратить.

Спасибо за помощь !

```
private LinkedList<LinkedList<Double>> reduceMatrix( LinkedList<LinkedList<Double>> matrix) {
    LinkedList<LinkedList<Double>> cacheMatrix = new LinkedList<>(matrix);
    cacheMatrix.get(0).remove(1);
    cacheMatrix = new LinkedList<>(matrix);
    System.out.println(cacheMatrix);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете посмотреть любую реализацию, скажем из [Open jdk](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l403) и увидеть, что там поэлементно добавляется всё.

Но у вас список списков. То есть, в итоговый список `cacheMatrix` добавляются ссылки на списки `LinkedList<Double>`. Поэтому, обращаясь к `cacheMatrix.get(0)`, вы, по сути, обращаетесь к `matrix.get(0)`.

Comment: блин, я так и думал... но переписывать иначе это же просто куча кода. Бред...